# R function with no return value

Tags: r, function

I was helping a friend of mine with some of his code. I didn't know how to explain the strange behavior, but I could tell him that his functions weren't explicitly returning anything. Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```
derp <- function(arg){
  arg <- arg+3
}

data <- derp(500)
data
#[1] 503
derp(500)
#nothing outputs
class(derp(500))
#[1] "numeric"
```

Is there a name for this that I can google? Why is this happening? Why isn't arg being destroyed after the call to derp() finishes?

Comment: Try `z <- derp(500); z` or `(derp(500))`. Also, see what happens if you don't assign `arg + 3` within your function's source and then use the function.

Comment: Without an `arg` at the end of the function, you're not printing anything. Try `(derp(500))`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between a function *returning* a value, and *printing* that value. By default, a function *returns* the value of the last expression evaluated, which in this case is the assignment

```
arg <- arg + 3
```

(Note that in R, an assignment is an expression that returns a value, in this case the value assigned.) This is why `data <- derp(500)` results in `data` containing 503.

However, the returned value is not printed to the screen by default, unless you isolate the function's final expression on its own line. This is one of those quirks in R. So if you want to see the value:

```
derp <- function(arg)
{
    arg <- arg + 3
    arg
}
```

or just

```
derp <- function(arg)
arg + 3
```

Comment: I don't agree with your statement "the returned value is not printed to the screen by default".  It IS printed by default.  The issue is that assignment sets the visibility to FALSE so that it doesn't display.  It's the same reason why when you do `a <- 3` you don't see '3' get printed as well.  Check out `withVisible(3)` compared to `withVisible(a <- 3)`

Comment: @Dason or even `a <- 3` vs `(a <- 3)`

Comment: Okay, good explanation. I guess it's more redundant than strange. It seems to just be chaining assignments a <- (b <- 3)

Comment: @Dason ... "unless you isolate the function's final expression on its own line"

Answer (score 4):

I often use `return(NULL)` for in the beginning of a function enclosed in some consistency checks, e.g. whether an output file would be overwritten. e.g.

```
some_function <- function(output_filename, overwrite = FALSE) {
  if (file.exists(output_filename)) {
    if (!overwrite) {
      return(NULL)
    }
  }
}
```

In this case the calling `some_function("file.path", overwrite = FALSE)` would return `NULL`. You can prevent that by modifying the return to:

```
...
return(invisible(NULL))
...
```

Answer (score 1):

the `arg` variable is being destroyed. A function in R will return the value of the last statement executed in the function unless a `return` statement is explicitly called.

In your case a copy of `arg` is the return value of your function. Example:

```
alwaysReturnSomething = function()
{
  x = runif(1)
  if(x<0.5) 20  else 10
}
> for(x in 1:10) cat(alwaysReturnSomething())
20202020102010101020
```

or:

```
alwaysReturnSomething <- function(){}
> z=alwaysReturnSomething()
> z
NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

This is curious behavior.

Basically `derp()`, it returns if you assign the output of `derp()`, and `derp()` does not return if you do not assign the result. This is because the assignment function (`<-`) returns using the invisible() function. see  [Make a function return silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122467/make-a-function-return-silently) for how that works.

You can see the same behavior with `derp2`:

```
derp2 <- function(arg) {
  invisible(arg + 3)
}
derp2(3)
# nothing
b <- derp2(3)
b
# 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to change the value of a variable in Global environment you can use `<<-` operator, but you still need to write the exact name of a variable in Global environment

```
derp <- function(arg){
  arg <- arg+3
  b<<-3
}
```

Try it and call `b`