# Make a function return silently

Tags: r, return

I would like to write an R function that returns silently, like what I get from the `barplot` function for example.

I mean that I can store an output in a variable if I do `output = myfunction()`, but this output does not get printed if I just use `myfunction()`.

Comment: Use `invisible`

Comment: I just had the wrong keywords, thank you !

Comment: You would have found `invisible` had you looked at the _See Also_ section of `?return`. The _See Also_ section is a great resource, especially when you're not sure of the correct keyword.

Comment: or you could have looked at the barplot source code, `barplot.default`

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I know that, but I checked and did not see it. And I know why, it's hidden behind `debug`

Comment: [Related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723034/howto-suppress-one-commands-output-in-r/2724317#2724317).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
myFunc <- function(x){
  invisible(x*2)
}

> myFunc(4)
> y <-myFunc(4)
> y
[1] 8
>
```

Comment: Mostly likely a duplicate

Comment: I would say it is usefull to keep this question for the keywork `silent` (instead of invisible). If you do not agree, I can delete it.

Comment: It shouldn't be deleted the question is can a duplicate be found that has already addressed the question.

Comment: I found it by searching 'silent', not 'invisible'

Comment: There's a problem with `invisible` though. If there is any code after the call to `invisible`, the function keeps going (it doesn't exit, as it would for `return`). `foo <- function(x=2) { invisible(x); print(1) }` called as `x <- foo()` should return 2, but instead keeps assigning 1 to x. This means that when `invisible` is not the end of the function (say you wanted to use a silent exit under some condition), you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: Playing around, it looks like you can wrap `invisible` in `return`, like so: `foo <- function(x=2) { return(invisible(x)); print(1) }` and this works just like I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

`invisible()` can be called at the end of the function to suppress any return value. Only downside is function will return `NULL`.

```
xf <- function() {
3 + 4
invisible()
}
```