# Make function return silently INCLUDING removing txt progress bar

Tags: r, function, progress, invisible

How do you get a function to return silently, INCLUDING POSSIBLE PROGRESS BARS???

I found this question: [Make a function return silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122467/make-a-function-return-silently)
and tested the suggested answer to use `invisible()`, but `invisible()` does not work for hiding text progress bars within functions!

Example function below:

```
myfun <- function(a){
  pb <- txtProgressBar(min=0, max=a, initial=0, style=3)
  foreach(b=1:a)%do%{
    Sys.sleep(1/20)
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, b)
  }
}
###Shows the progress bar
myfunout1 <- invisible(myfun(30))

###Still shows the progress bar
invisible(myfunout1 <- myfun(30))
```

Comment: If you type`invisible(myfun(30))` in the console, you may see that it does not return an object. It does print the progress bar on the screen.

Comment: maybe you are after something like `sink`

Comment: `txtProgressBar` uses `cat`, so the top couple answers at the dupe seem good. I'm a little more skeptical of Sacha's answer - I'd stick with the `sink` or `capture.output` methods.

Comment: @Suren, yes that is what I am trying to avoid is the progress bar on the screen