# r create function from lm coefficients

Tags: r, for-loop, regression, lm

The code below displays the problem. I ran a degree-four-polynomial regression `lm` on the data.frame `df`to obtain `model4`. 
Then I createD the regression function `fhat4`. This works as intended.

I want to generalize this to any degree of polynomial. So, I use `poly` to create `modeln`. This matches `model4`. But I am not able to create the appropriate function `fhatn`. Perhaps this is something to do with the for loop?

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(0.3543937637005, 0.674911001464352, 0.21966037643142, 
0.14723521983251, 0.36166316177696, 0.975983075099066, 0.539355604210868, 
0.294046462047845, 0.853777077747509, 0.634912414476275), y = c(0.0120776002295315, 
0.655085238162428, 0.310665819328278, 0.525274415733293, 0.938241509487852, 
0.520828885724768, 0.241615766659379, 0.724816955626011, 0.808277940144762, 
0.358921303786337)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

############################################# 
model4 <- lm(y~x+I(x^2)+I(x^3)+I(x^4), data=df)

fhat4 <- function (x) {
  model4$coefficients[1]+
  model4$coefficients[2]*x+
  model4$coefficients[3]*x^2+
  model4$coefficients[4]*x^3+
  model4$coefficients[5]*x^4
  }

fhat4(2)

############################################# 
modeln <- lm(y~poly(x,4,raw=TRUE), data=df)

fhatn <- function (x) {
  fn <- 0
  for (i in 0:5){
    fn <- fn + modeln$coefficients[i+1]*x^i
  }
}

fhatn(4)
```

Comment: Does the function `predict.lm` not provide already such a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `for` loop should only go from 0 to 4 not till 5. Also your function does not return anything so you could add a `return(fn)` at the end.

Anyway, you can implement the same function without any loops:

```
modeln <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 4, raw = TRUE), data = df)

fhatn <- function (x) {
  sum(x^(seq_along(coef(modeln)) - 1) * coef(modeln))
}

fhatn(2)
[1] -150.6643
```

Note that `coef(modeln)` is an alternative to `modeln$coefficients`.

Or as Vincent said in the comments you can use the predict function:

```
predict(modeln, newdata = data.frame(x = 2))
-150.6643
```

Comment: The key was simply the lack of return(fn). Many thanks. You're right of course that `i` need only go up to 4. Since that was a typo, one could edit that bit out of the original question.

Comment: Note that a function without any return value still returns something but that something is not printed out in the console. You can try `print(fhatn(2))` for your old function `fhatn` and it should also work. Check also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541012/r-function-with-no-return-value).

Comment: `coef(fm)` and `fm$coefficients` are not always equivalent .  In general, `coef(fm)` should be used.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck good to know, thank you. Can you elaborate a bit more or do you know a good source?

Comment: Look at the source.  You can see that it does give the same result as `fm$coefficients` in some cases and not in others.  Also `fm$coefficients` depends on the particular data structure that `lm` uses internally whereas if that were to change in the future then `coef` would presumably change in a corresponding way but `fm$coefficients` might break.   Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding